# List is NULL while POST from View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I use the below Action to allow the user to see a preview of Excel import

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult ImportVerify()
{
    string temp_sessionname = "ImportedData_" + User.Identity.Name;
    List<ProjectImportModel> view_model = (List<ProjectImportModel>)TempData[temp_sessionname];
    return View(view_model);
}
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult ImportVerify(List<ProjectImportModel> model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

And on View i am using a table to show the List of imported data from excel and ask user to confirm the action of import

My view is like this

```
<h2>Import Verify</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
 //table with all details and a submit button in the end

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10" style="text-align:center;">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />         
    </div>
</div>
}
```

And model is

```
public class ProjectImportModel
```

{
     public string Page { get; set; }

```
 public string Author { get; set; }

 public string Translator { get; set; }

 public string Holder { get; set; }

public string Title { get; set; }

public string TrTitle { get; set; }
//and similar 20 more properties of string type
```

}

But on POST the list is null

Is any way to get the list back at POST event. My intension is just to allow the preview to user

Or do i need to refill List from TempData @ post as well?

Comment: Where do you set your model in your view?

Comment: Show how you generate the controls for all the properties of your model

Comment: Can you give us the full code for the form as we can't see how the lists is being sent over. Also can you provide the code for your ProjectImportModel class, please?

Comment: Can you please show us your `ProjectImportModel` properties?

Comment: Question editted with model properties

Answer (score 3):

In order to post a collection back you need to index the properties, if they're readonly you can just use HiddenFor with a model.
If you want the user to edit them, change them to `TextBoxFor's` instead or the control that you data requires.

```
@model List<ProjectImportModel>
<h2>Import Verify</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
 //table with all details and a submit button in the end

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10" style="text-align:center;">
        @for(var i = 0 ; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
          @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Foo) 
          @Model[i].Foo <br/>
        }
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />         
    </div>
</div>
}
```

I just used a dummy property of `Foo` without seeing your model.

Obviously you would want to display the data too.

[**Model Binding To A List**](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)

Comment: I already get the list from a TempData on GET . Is any perfomance drawback for relaoding from Tempdata @ POST as well? I already mention that in the end of question

Comment: I have to add Hiddenfield for almost 16 properties

Comment: @JMat I prefer to use strongly typed models, less room for error and that is how I post them back to the controller.

Comment: But how can i make it as a strongly typed model . In my case i have a model with 15 properties and List of items . Can u suggest some samples

Comment: @JMat You are already passing back a strongly typed model to the view, just add the `@model List<ProjectImportModel>` at the top of your view and you are good to go. Then you will be able to index them as  `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Author ) ` in your loop. :)

Comment: If OP is not editing properties, this would seriously degrade performance. The collection should be retrieved again from a repository if its needed.

Comment: @StephenMuecke So posting back is more of an overhead than re-calling a database. What not put an answer to that effect then? That's what this place is for. :)

Comment: Only OP can really test that to be sure, but in most cases a database call will be less overhead than sending all that extra data to the view (the hidden inputs) and sending it all back again unchanged (and there is potential for overposting attacks). But then again I'm not even sure if OP is editing or not - still has not shown the view :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Generally, it's much faster to send/receive some extra HTML/post data than it is to query a database. An extra round-trip to the database is overhead. As for over-posting, that's outside the realms of this answer and is largely unrelated to be honest.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I agree with above, db is usually an over-head IMO and question is growing like an octopus from the original title which seemed to me to be `Is any way to get the list back at POST event`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the snippet code that set your `TempData`. So I intend that you set it in another Action and then redirect to the `ImportVerify` Action

TempData keep the information for the time of an HTTP Request. This mean only from one page to another. It's mean that after redirect to your `ImportVerify Get` Action the data is expired. If you want to keep the data you can try the following ways:

- Create a hidden List in your page
- Use `Session` instead of `TempData`

Comment: Because `TempData` is a short-temp `Session`, so I recommend you use `Session` to store the List and you can delete when you need.

Answer (score 0):

There are some requirements to post a list back to a controller. Specifically, indexes must be 0-based and unbroken (example, you can bind a list with indexes [0], [1], [2] but not one with [0], [1], [3] or [1], [2], [3].

Alternatively, you could write a custom model binder to parse the request body the way you like.

More on this here: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

EDIT: 
Here is an example on how to do it:

Given the following model

```
public class ExampleModel
{
    public int Field1 {get; set;}
    public string Field2 {get; set;}
}
```

And the following actions

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult ImportVerify()
{
    List<ExampleModel> model = //populate the list somehow
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult ImportVerify(List<ExampleModel> model)
{
    //do something
}
```

The example view "ImportVerify.cshtml" would be:

```
@model List<ExampleModel>

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    for(var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
       <div>
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Field1);
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Field2);
            <p>
                Value @i : Field1 = @m[i].Field1 , Field2 = @m[i].Field2
            </p> 
        </div>
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
}
```

Also, I would revise your logic a bit, to avoid the use of TempData (generally bad practice) and to allow strongly typed views.